# $|\chi(\mathfrak{a})| = 1$ for any ideal $\mathfrak{a}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, $Cl(K)$ the ideal class group, $\chi: Cl(K) \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ a homomorphism. If $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ is any ideal, let $[\mathfrak{a}]$ denote its ideal class in $Cl(K)$, and define $\chi(\mathfrak{a}) = \chi([\mathfrak{a}])$.

How do I see that $|\chi(\mathfrak{a})| = 1$ for any ideal $\mathfrak{a}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the group $Cl(K)$ is finite (Dirichlet) every element in it is torsion, thus is sent to a torsion element of $\mathbb C^*$, i.e. a root of unity, necessarily of absolute value $1$.